# Class for typecasting an Activity to an interface

Tags: java

In several places, I have some code that looks like the following, the only difference is in the type of listener.

```
public class CustomFragment extends android.app.Fragment {
    SomeListener listener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(android.app.Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // duplication
        //     ||
        //    \||/
        //     \/
        try {
            listener = (SomeListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement SomeListener");
        }
    }
}
```

To avoid duplication, I wrote this simple class:

```
public class TypeConvertor {
    private final Object whatNeedToCast;

    public static TypeConvertor cast(Object whatNeedToCast) {
        return new TypeConvertor(whatNeedToCast);
    }

    private TypeConvertor(Object whatNeedToCast) {
        this.whatNeedToCast = whatNeedToCast;
    }

    public <OtherType> OtherType to(Class<OtherType> toWhichToCast) {
        try {
            return (OtherType) whatNeedToCast;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(
                    whatNeedToCast.toString() + " must implement " + toWhichToCast.getName()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

And the previous code is simplified to the following:

```
public class CustomFragment extends android.app.Fragment {
    SomeListener listener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(android.app.Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        listener = TypeConvertor.cast(activity).to(SomeListener.class);
    }
}
```

But I do not like name `TypeConvertor`. Help me pick a better name (and help refactor this simple class if needed).

Comment: I don't understand yourproblem but, instead of having a type converter, should CustomerFragment be a Generic class, whose type variable is the type of SomeListener (so that a specific CustomerFragment type supports a specific type of SomeListener/Activity)?

Comment: Activity can implement several interfaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me like what you have done here is to create an entire class to avoid duplicating one line. (Or OK, 5 lines if counting the try-catch statement)

I don't agree with the need to create a class for this. Especially not a generic one, since this line of code:

```
return (OtherType) whatNeedToCast;
```

Does the same thing as:

```
return OtherType.class.cast(whatNeedToCast);
```

So all you are doing additionally is to wrap it in another exception which is explained just slightly better. But personally, I think this message...

> com.yourpackage.YourActivity@1df59a42 must implement com.yourpackage.SomeListener

...actually says just as much as the default one, if you would not catch the exception in the first place:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.yourpackage.YourActivity to com.yourpackage.SomeListener

Actually, `Cannot cast (class) to (class)` would say **even more** if you would override the `toString` method in `YourActivity`.

If you are writing these classes to be used as a library by many other people, then it could be good practice to explain that the activity must implement some interface. Otherwise, I don't see the point of it. But either way, there's no need to create an entire class for this.

## Summary:

Get rid of your additional class, just cast your `activity` to `SomeListener` and don't catch the exception to throw your own.

So in the end, all that remains is this one line:

```
listener = (SomeListener) activity;
```

And it's perfectly OK to duplicate that.